# How Max join size works?

Tags: mysql

When Using:

```
mysql>explain extended
select a.included_id, a.portfolio_id
FROM included_transactions a
left join  transactions b;
```

I have an estimation of (31231*132):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   index       portfolio_id    5       31231   100 Using index
1   SIMPLE  b   ref portfolio_id    portfolio_id    5   damsv2.a.portfolio_id   132 100 Using index
```

But with `MAX_join_size=(31231*132)=4122492` is not enough to block the query. I have to set `MAX_join_size=` almost `770000` to block the query.

Even if it is an estimation how does MySQL know that my query is going to exceed `Max_join_size`?

Comment: Your are missing a `ON` for the join.  Your query should run correctly with the right `ON` condition.

Comment: the query is incomplete, surprised it runs at all, I would expect it produce an error. I even tried and `cannot run` a left join that is without its on condition. Did you forget to copy the whole query perhaps?

Comment: Yes the end is missing.

Comment: Here the complete query:explain extended
select a.included_id, a.portfolio_id
FROM included_transactions a
left join  transactions b on a.portfolio =b. Portfolio.